# Stack Overflow for employers/companies?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I think I remembered there was a site like Stack Overflow but for employers or companies where they could ask questions like how are other companies doing such and such ... or was I just dreaming?

Comment: And now you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you were thinking of http://answers.onstartups.com/, a Stack Exchange beta site.

**Update:** The above site got closed a couple years after this question was asked, but there is now [a new Startups Stack Exchange beta site](https://startups.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is the site alive?

Comment: @yasmin it was at the time I originally wrote this answer, but was later closed. There is a new Startups Stack Exchange site now, though. Answer updated!